# How can I get the status of push notification permission from browser?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing an web site in PWA way, I'd like to use push notification function.

But I can not find the way to get the status of push notification permission(not asked/blocked/permitted) from browser with javascript code.

Is there any handy way to get it? Or any complicated way?

Currently I'm using firebase messaging's `requestPermission()` function, which always request the permission to user. I want to get the status of permission without any request to user.

Comment: with that method it return a callback and you can run your logic in that callback based on permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `Notification` object in browser. I could check permission status with `Notification.permission` which returns `granted`, `default`, `denied` in string.

Comment: Not a function for me